# how to join two columns side by side in MDX in SSAS

Tags: ssas, dmx-ssas

I have a query where it will give Schema Columns of the table.

```
Select level_caption from $system.MDSchema_levels
Where [Cube_name] = 'Quote' 
AND [Dimension_Unique_name]= [QUOTE TABLE NAME] AND NOT[LEVEL_IS_VISIBLE]

Select level_caption from $system.MDSchema_levels
Where [Cube_name] = 'Quote' 
AND [Dimension_Unique_name]= [QUOTE TABLE NAME] AND [LEVEL_IS_VISIBLE]
```

Here I'm going to get Visible and Non Visible Columns

how I can put 
Visible and NON-Visible Columns side by side 
OUTPUT :

```
Visible  Non-Visible
col1      col2
col3      col4
col5      col7
col6
```

Comment: No in SSAS only @SouravA

Comment: I don't think it's possible to achieve this as DMX(language of DMV's) do not support SQL keywords such as `CASE`, `JOIN`. Try handling it in the reporting tool.

Comment: This isn't MDX.   In MDX you would just put the `LEVEL_IS_VISIBLE` dimension on columns.